# How to insert accented characters in PostreSQL using PHP and ezSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql, ezsql

Using **PHP**, the following *string* was generated

```
INSERT INTO persons ("username","firstname") VALUES ('nino','Niño')
```

but when tried to execute the statement at runtime like so:

```
<?php
...
$query = 'INSERT INTO persons ("username","firstname")'." VALUES ('nino','Niño')";
$result = $pgsql->query( $query );
?>
```

it was not inserted to the table, but when I issued the same statement in the **phpPgAdmin**, it was inserted.

Is there a working way to insert accented characters in **PostreSQL** using **PHP** & **ezSQL**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$data = 'Niño'
$escaped = pg_escape_string(utf8_encode($data));
$query  = "INSERT INTO correspondence (name, data) VALUES ('nino', '{$escaped}')"
```

Comment: I have added `pg_escape_string()` just now but it seems to escape only the single and double quotes. This didn't fixed it.

Comment: yeap, it needs `utf8_encode()` to work. However, `pg_escape_string()` may no longer be necessary

Answer (score 0):

you need to use universal text finder utf8 encoding to work. whereas pg escape strings cannot be considered